# How To Keep and Add Another Variable In Java?

Tags: java, parameter-passing, modeling

New to programming, so please, go easy.

Im working on a calculator app for class. I have to set up the addition, subtraction, multiplication and division methods.

```
package part1.code;

import part1.user_interface.CalculatorUI;

public class Calculator {

private static final int BASE = 10;
private int _value;
private int _va;
private CalculatorUI _ui;

public Calculator(CalculatorUI calculatorUI) {
    _ui = calculatorUI;
    _value = 0;

}

public void digit_0_keyPressed() {
    _value = _value * BASE + 0;
    _ui.updateDisplay();
}
public void digit_1_keyPressed() {
    _value = _value * BASE + 1;
    _ui.updateDisplay();
}
public void digit_2_keyPressed() {
    _value = _value * BASE + 2;
    _ui.updateDisplay();
}
public void digit_3_keyPressed() {
    _value = _value * BASE + 3;
    _ui.updateDisplay();
}
public void digit_4_keyPressed() {
    _value = _value * BASE + 4;
    _ui.updateDisplay();
}
public void digit_5_keyPressed() {
    _value = _value * BASE + 5;
    _ui.updateDisplay();
}
public void digit_6_keyPressed() {
    _value = _value * BASE + 6;
    _ui.updateDisplay();
}
public void digit_7_keyPressed() {
    _value = _value * BASE + 7;
    _ui.updateDisplay();
}
public void digit_8_keyPressed() {
    _value = _value * BASE + 8;
    _ui.updateDisplay();
}
public void digit_9_keyPressed() {
    _value = _value * BASE + 9;
    _ui.updateDisplay();
}
public void clear_keyPressed() {
    _value = 0;
    _ui.updateDisplay();
}
public int getValue() {
    return _value;
}

public void equal_keyPressed() {
    _value = _value;
    _ui.updateDisplay();

    // TODO Define this method
}

public void add_keyPressed() {
    _value = 



    _ui.updateDisplay();

    // TODO Define this method

  }
}
```

Now, for example, a basic thing you would do is 1+1. For add_keyPressed, I'm trying to get to 1+1 = 2, instead of 1+1 = 11. So, I"m trying to hold the value  input, and add the new value at the same time. This sounds like I'm parameter passing ( I could be wrong ), or modelling, but I'm not quite sure.  And I wouldn't know how to do this without Static ( which is an absolute forbidden in my class ), which from what I'm seeing others do, is the standard. 
Also, within all of this, a method signature -

public int perform(int arg)

Has to be included.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is your question? what do you want? are you stuck at something?

Comment: You will need to store the first number in _value then the operator and then the second value in _va? are you stuck with this?

Comment: Sorry
Forgot, _va was an attempt to try to instatiate another variable, its a throwaway I'll delete.
I bascially want to have add_keyPressed how another value in place while I add another value, such as that 1 + 1 ( which holds 1 while I add another 1) = 2, instead of 1+1 = 11.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the list of changes
1. Add an enum for operator
2. Add an operator variable to the class
3. Change the constructor to set default value for operator variable
4. Update equals key pressed method
5. Update add key pressed method

```
public class Calculator {

    private static final int BASE = 10;
    private int _value;
    private int _va;
    private CalculatorUI _ui;
    private Operator op;

    private enum Operator {
        ADD, SUB, MUL, DIV, NO_OPERATION
    };

    public Calculator(CalculatorUI calculatorUI) {
        op = Operator.NO_OPERATION;
        _ui = calculatorUI;
        _value = 0;
    }

    public void digit_0_keyPressed() {
        _value = _value * BASE + 0;
        _ui.updateDisplay();
    }

    public void digit_1_keyPressed() {
        _value = _value * BASE + 1;
        _ui.updateDisplay();
    }

    public void digit_2_keyPressed() {
        _value = _value * BASE + 2;
        _ui.updateDisplay();
    }

    public void digit_3_keyPressed() {
        _value = _value * BASE + 3;
        _ui.updateDisplay();
    }

    public void digit_4_keyPressed() {
        _value = _value * BASE + 4;
        _ui.updateDisplay();
    }

    public void digit_5_keyPressed() {
        _value = _value * BASE + 5;
        _ui.updateDisplay();
    }

    public void digit_6_keyPressed() {
        _value = _value * BASE + 6;
        _ui.updateDisplay();
    }

    public void digit_7_keyPressed() {
        _value = _value * BASE + 7;
        _ui.updateDisplay();
    }

    public void digit_8_keyPressed() {
        _value = _value * BASE + 8;
        _ui.updateDisplay();
    }

    public void digit_9_keyPressed() {
        _value = _value * BASE + 9;
        _ui.updateDisplay();
    }

    public void clear_keyPressed() {
        _value = 0;
        _ui.updateDisplay();
    }

    public int getValue() {
        return _value;
    }

    public void equal_keyPressed(String uimessage) {
        if (Operator.ADD.equals(op)) {
            _value += _va;
        } else if (Operator.MUL.equals(op)) {
            _value *= _va;
        } else if (Operator.DIV.equals(op)) {
            _value = _va / _value;
        } else if (Operator.SUB.equals(op)) {
            _value = _va - _value;
        }
        _va = 0;
        op = Operator.NO_OPERATION;
        _ui.updateDisplay();
    }

    public void add_keyPressed() {
        if (!Operator.NO_OPERATION.equals(op)) {
            equal_keyPressed();
        } else {
        _ui.updateDisplay();
        }

        _va = _value;
        _value = 0;
        op = Operator.ADD;
    }

    public void mul_keyPressed() {
        if (!Operator.NO_OPERATION.equals(op)) {
            equal_keyPressed();
        } else {
            _ui.updateDisplay();
        }

        _va = _value;
        _value = 0;
        op = Operator.MUL;
    }
}
```